# How do you sort PowerShell output by a specific column in the output so it is the first column?

Tags: powershell

I am running this PowerShell script in a Windows domain. The output is below. My question is how to sort the output by a specific column in the output so it is the first column. I would like the column with the "SMTP" to be the first column in the output.

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit=-1
Import-Csv "\\server\Input.csv" |
    Foreach {Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($_.EID)'" -Properties SamAccountName, Enabled, proxyAddresses } |
    Select-Object SamAccountName, Enabled, proxyAddresses |
    Sort-Object proxyAddresses |
    FT -Wrap -AutoSize

SamAccountName Enabled proxyAddresses                                                                                                                                                                   
-------------- ------- --------------                                                                                                                                                                   
name           True    smtp:name@address.com, SMTP:name@address.com
```

Comment: You can specify the property order in the final call to `Format-Table`.  For example: `Format-Table -Property proxyAddresses Enabled SamAccountName`

Comment: Im unclear if you're asking for the `proxyAddresses` property to be arranged first or if you're asking that the value starting with `SMTP` to appear first in the `proxyAddresses` array

Comment: Flip these two columns smtp:name@address.com, SMTP:name@address.com so the column with the "SMTP is the first column.

Comment: Those are not columns, they're property values. What you're asking is to create a new array.

Comment: I always thought the array was for input not output. I'll read up on that. Thank you.

Comment: What you want to do is doable, but I honestly don't see the point. Wouldn't it be better to have one object per value in the `proxyAddresses` column? at least you can sort and filter later having something like that

Comment: I exactly need each proxyaddress each user has.

Comment: The input is a bunch of users by EmployeeID. I need to output all of their proxyaddress and hopefully make the SMTP the first in the output array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're looking for is re-arranging the values in the [`proxyAddresses` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-proxyaddresses), for this you would need to either **update the property** or **re-create the array**. This example demonstrates how to re-create the array.

Given this test set:

```
$set = 0..10 | ForEach-Object {
    $user = 'testUser' + $_
    [pscustomobject]@{
        SamAccountName = $user
        Enabled        = $true
        proxyAddresses = @(
            "smtp:${user}secondary@domain.com",
            "SMTP:$user@domain.com",
            "smtp:$user@otherDomain.com"
        )
    }
}
```

Using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) with [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) you can generate a new array with the sorted values starting with `SMTP`:

```
$set | Select-Object SamAccountName, Enabled, @{
    Name       = 'proxyAddresses'
    Expression = { $_.proxyAddresses | Sort-Object { $_.StartsWith('smtp') } }
}
```

The output would become something like this:

```
SamAccountName Enabled proxyAddresses
-------------- ------- --------------
testUser0         True {SMTP:testUser0@domain.com, smtp:te...
testUser1         True {SMTP:testUser1@domain.com, smtp:te...
testUser2         True {SMTP:testUser2@domain.com, smtp:te...
testUser3         True {SMTP:testUser3@domain.com, smtp:te...
testUser4         True {SMTP:testUser4@domain.com, smtp:te...
...
...
```

However, I would personally recommend you to create a new object per value in the `proxyAddresses` attribute, this way, you would have sortable and filterable Data when exported.

```
$set | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($smtp in $_.proxyAddresses | Sort-Object { $_.StartsWith('smtp') }) {
        $_ | Select-Object SamAccountName, Enabled, @{
            Name = 'proxyAddress'
            Expression = { $smtp }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the export would look like this, always starting with the `SMTP` value first for each object:

```
SamAccountName Enabled proxyAddress
-------------- ------- ------------
testUser0         True SMTP:testUser0@domain.com
testUser0         True smtp:testUser0secondary@domain.com
testUser0         True smtp:testUser0@otherDomain.com
testUser1         True SMTP:testUser1@domain.com
testUser1         True smtp:testUser1secondary@domain.com
testUser1         True smtp:testUser1@otherDomain.com
testUser2         True SMTP:testUser2@domain.com
...
...
```

Comment: This first output works for me but it keeps telling me I am missing a closing '}'

testUser0         True {SMTP:testUser0@domain.com, smtp:te...
testUser1         True {SMTP:testUser1@domain.com, smtp:te...
testUser2         True {SMTP:testUser2@domain.com, smtp:te...

Comment: @D-a-n_L the code from my answer or your code? if it's your code update your question with it

Comment: Your second example

Comment: @D-a-n_L it works fine in the example answer. You have probably copy pasted it wrongly. I cant see your screen so Im just assuming.

Comment: Import-Csv "\\Server\Input.csv" |
Foreach {Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($_.EID)'" -Properties EmployeeID, SamAccountName, Enabled, ProxyAddresses } |
Select-Object EmployeeID, SamAccountName, Enabled, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like '*@skagitregionalhealth.org') -join ";"}} |
Export-Csv -Path "\\Server\Export.csv" -NoTypeInformation